# Huawei media pad(hws7300w) is not supported for my application while downloading from android play

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play

For one of the user is not able to download application from Android Play and showing message as "Device is not supported".

Application setting in manifest file:

```
<manifest 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:versionCode="10" 
    android:versionName="1.7" 
    package="com.companyname.appname"
    android:installLocation="auto">

    <uses-sdk 
        android:minSdkVersion="8" 
        android:targetSdkVersion="8"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
```

Application setting in Android Play:

```
API level: 8-16+
Supported screens: small-xlarge
OpenGL textures: all

Screen layouts: SMALL NORMAL LARGE XLARGE
Required device features
android.hardware.camera
android.hardware.location
android.hardware.location.gps
android.hardware.screen.landscape
android.hardware.screen.portrait
android.hardware.telephony
android.hardware.touchscreen
android.hardware.wifi
```

The user is trying to download from device "Huawei media pad(hws7300w)" with OS v2.2 and its screen size "800 x 1280 pixels, 7.0 inches (~216 ppi pixel density)"
If i check in device availability list in android play. This device is present in unsupported list [image: check this]

Can anyone let me know the changes in manifest to support this device/tablet.

Comment: Did you specify "copy protection" in Google Play?

Comment: I forgot to add this thing. The Copy protection is set to "Off (Application can be copied from the device)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:
Sorry, you're right! I found this [faq](http://www.huaweidevice.com/worldwide/faq.do?method=getFaqInfo&questionId=7568) that suggests to allow installing of non-market-apps. What I also have found inside the faq is that it seems it doesn't support telephony by default, as stated [here](http://www.huaweidevice.com/worldwide/faq.do?method=getFaqInfo&questionId=7564). So its probably the telephony-service that blocks the installation, rather than the Cam.

You can add a [uses-feature](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html) with required=false if your app CAN work without Telephony.

Comment: But as i see on huawei site, the device is having camera. Have a look into "Tech Specs" tab

Comment: Thank for pointing this part. I will look into it and get back to you.

Comment: As i didn't got much updates on this issue from my client. But i feel your point seems to valid, it could b due to telephony not cam. Anyways i will accept your answer and thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check this question:

[Why does the Google Play store say my Android app is incompatible with my own device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10475954/why-does-the-google-play-store-say-my-android-app-is-incompatible-with-my-own-de)

It contains a lot of good answers for this problem. For me the problem for this error message was the CAMERA permission: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11243627/372838 and since the camera can be launched through an INTENT you don't necessarily need this permission.