# Google play excluding my app due to cache partition size

Tags: android, google-play

I have uploaded my app to [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tfg) and now I realize that it's filtered for some devices like HTC Wildfire S.
Searching in the web, I found out that it may be due to size of cache partition. My app is 42MB, and I think the cache partition of Wildfire S is 35MB, so it's incompatible according to Google Play.

Actually, the app is not incompatible, since I installed it manually in a Wildfire S and works ok.

> So, my question is, how can I make my app compatible in Google Play
>   for those devices? Is there any workaround, like dividing my app in a
>   expasion file, or something similar?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10475954/why-does-the-google-play-store-say-my-android-app-is-incompatible-with-my-own-de?rq=1