# incompatible app with some devices while minSdkVersion = 1

Tags: android, sdk, incompatibility

I created an app that uses the `android-viewflow` and it has `minSdkVersion="1"` , but when I publish it on Google Play I found out that it's incompatible with just these devices

- Samsung Galaxy Mini– GT-S5570
- Samsung Galaxy Pocket– GT-S5302
- Samsung Galaxy Pro– GT-B7510
- Samsung Galaxy– gt-i7500
- Samsung Galaxy Pocket– GT-S5302B
- Samsung Galaxy Fit– GT-S5670

but when I install the APK in one of these phones it works fine, till now I still can't find what did I do wrong to make the app incompatible with those devices.

PS: in my android stats the app works fine with all the platform Version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10475954/why-does-the-google-play-store-say-my-android-app-is-incompatible-with-my-own-de).

Compatibility is not only about the minimum SDK version, apparently app (.apk) size and some other things also have to do with it.