# Android app is supported by 0 devices

Tags: android, google-play

I'm having trouble with the Google Play store that insists that my app is supported by 0 devices. I've tried all the solutions I found on SO and elsewhere. This isn't about the apk being inactive, it gets activated be default and I've even tried to deactivate and reactivate it.

I've tested it on my Galaxy Nexus and it works very well, there's no reason for it to be incompatible with every single Android device...

Here's my manifest file:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.accelerometer"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.screen.portrait"
    android:required="false" />
```

The full project source can be found here: https://github.com/Nurgak/Android-Bluetooth-Remote-Control as it's open-source.

This is what I see on Google Play.
[image]

The 5 features being

```
android.hardware.ACCELEROMETER
android.hardware.BLUETOOTH
android.hardware.CAMERA
android.hardware.camera.AUTOFOCUS
android.hardware.TOUCHSCREEN
```

And 4 permissions

```
android.permission.BLUETOOTH
android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN
android.permission.CAMERA
android.permission.INTERNET
```

I'm absolutely appalled by their support too, I've only gotten generic "hey have you looked at our FAQs?" replies to e-mails.

Comment: Thanks for the sreenshot. I recomend always give a look to the "APK details" in order to review that everything is allright.

Comment: I was getting "supported by 150 devices" and changed this by lowering my minSdkVersion

Answer (score 18, accepted):

- Try changing the apk name from `com.bluetooth` to `com.nurgak.bluetoothremote`
- Try setting all the `uses-feature"-tag`s to `false`
- Try removing all permissions (I know the app won't work without them, but just for the sake of figuring out why Google Play says that the app supports 0 devices)

> P.S.: You don't need `android.hardware.screen.portrait` if you set it
>   to `false`, anyway. It doesn't have an effect in that case.

Comment: It was the `android.hardware.ACCELEROMETER` that should've been `android.hardware.sensor.ACCELEROMETER`. The renaming wasn't necessary.

Comment: I'm glad you were able to fix it!

Comment: Thanks. It helps me :)

Comment: Please take in consideration to change the accepted answer to the one of Gouda Elalfy.

Answer (score 55):

I had faced a similar issue when I had declared camera hardware in uses-feature tag in manifest file in my application as follows:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera">
```

If you don't specify the android:required attribute it defaults to "true". Thus, Google Play Store will assume that the application will not work unless the camera hardware is present.

Once you set android:required to false as given below, Play Store will accept the APK and will show a list of devices available for the application.

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
```

You may also look for misspellings on features descriptors. For supported feature descriptors see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#features-reference

For more information: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html

Comment: Amazing thank you helped with our Xamarin app receiving the same error.

Answer (score 40):

Go to **release management**  then -> **Device catalog**, and select any Unsupported device to show its details and you will see the reason why this device doesn't supported

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can this be set as the accepted answer? It provides exact instructions on how to troubleshoot the issue instead of trying to guess what the problem is!

Comment: Mine says "Available on 0 device" on the private alpha track, but when i open the device catalog, or even open "release details" says 2000+ devices supported. App not appearing in the store. There is definitely a bug in my case.

Answer (score 35):

We recently moved to Android Studio (from Eclipse) and I was trying to upload my first production version built with Studio, and I got the dreaded "Supported Android Devices 0" message when I uploaded my APK.  The solution ended up being how we were including the apache commons codec library.

Check your build.gradle file - if you see something like:

`compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.codec:1.+'`

change it to:

`compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.+'`

My theory is that the "org.apache.directory.studio" part of the namespace is screwing up the developer console and using the shorthand works fine.

How did I discover this?  Well, I didn't, [they did](https://github.com/robot-mitya/rosjava_bootstrap/commit/f9acae776f991374428100f8193c5f3861ca9514) I just got lucky and found their commit message via a Google search.

Comment: This was a life saving answer! in my case it was the other issue mentioned on in the page you mentioned i.e. `compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'` that was the culprit. 

I had to change it to `compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'`

Comment: Thanks a lot... It saved the life of my first android app. Have changed to `commons-io:commons-io:x.x` and it got supported by 1000's of devices.

Comment: Thank you very much, my problem resolve after 2 days.
I change `compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.lang:2.6'` to
`compile 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6'`
and problem resolved.

Answer (score 32):

To me the issue was this line in the manifest file:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" />
```

I would've spend maybe quite some time to track it down but, fortunately, Google provides in the developer console the ability to contact them via chat (for some reason that option is not present anymore ATMW, maybe it's capped?). They were able to pinpoint the issue in a few minutes, I had to change the above line to

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" android:required="false" />
```

Quite a time saver, so thanks Google!

Comment: Thanks a lot..Work like charm

Answer (score 21):

Sometimes the reason for this is a third party library that you have referenced. If you can find which one is it and if you can remove it you can solve the problem.

In my case I had to remove:

> org.apache.commons.io:2.4

Comment: No need to remove the dependency - see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32749726/1103584

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem. My solution was to write this line correct in the manifest:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.barometer" android:required="true" />
```

Answer (score 2):

though this question is answered, some additional amendments,,
remove any .jar dependency (specially common-io.*.jar dependency).
i was able to resolve the issue after solving dependency issue.

Answer (score 0):

In case of using gradle, make sure all the manifest in your project are aligned to the min/max/target sdk version.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a problem with 0 supported devices, but the cause was different. **One of the libraries would create a `lib/README.txt` file inside the generated APK**. Upon uploading the APK to the Google Play Console, the `lib/README.txt` file would be picked up by the APK analysis tool and would be considered as a native library which wasn't supported by any device.

I have fixed the issue by removing the file from the APK using following Gradle configuration in `build.gradle` file:

```
android {
    ...

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'lib/README.txt'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. Fixed by removing all  in the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is late to answer, I face the same problem. With setting all users-features as `false`, play store still shows zero devices supported.

Here is solution, hope will help someone

```
   <uses-feature
            android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
            android:required="true" />
```

Also

```
<supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

Hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

I found that this issue is caused by `AndroidManifest.xml` file.
Just replace

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.accelerometer" android:required="true"/>
```

with

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor.accelerometer" android:required="true"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Mine related to the Zxing barcode scanner features.  I chatted with developer support who identified that i had an issue with the `android.hardware.camera.autoFocus` property.  Support wasn't sure what I needed to do in order to fix the issue.  Using answers above, I added  `android:required="false"` in the `manifest` file.

From 0 devices to `Supported Android devices 7,856`

Change from:

```
<!--barcode scan-->
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autoFocus"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
```

to

```
<!--barcode scan-->
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autoFocus" android:required="false"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
```