# Google Play Supported devices 0

Tags: android, google-play

have a problem with the already published application on Google Play. The application in store, but no one can download, because I getting "Supported devices 0". I did refactor the project, removed all unnecessary with the manifest. Compiled a new apk, and again "Supported devices 0". I have already a few days trying to solve this problem, but until the "Supported devices 0". I spread the current manifest, project structure, and screenshots from Google Play page publication. Application Activated. Really need your help.
(Sorry for my english)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="my.application"
      android:versionCode="2"
      android:versionName="1.1">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"
              android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>

    <permission android:name="my.application.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
                android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
                  android:required="true"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="my.application.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                 android:name="my.application.activity.delegateApplication"
                 android:allowBackup="true"
                 android:launchMode="singleInstance"
                 android:largeHeap="true"
                 android:label="@string/app_name" >
       <activity
                android:name=".activity.SomeActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".SomeClass"
                  android:theme="@style/CustomTheme"
                  android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                >
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".SomeClass1"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
                  android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                >

        </activity>
        <activity
                android:name=".SomeClass3"
                android:launchMode="singleInstance"
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />

        ...

        <activity android:name=".SomeClassN"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
                  android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                >
        </activity>


        <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                android:value="my_code"
                />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

pictures
unfortunately I can not post it pictures, just links to them

http://leahov.com/pic/1.png

http://leahov.com/pic/2.png

Comment: Please check this solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/14020303/3392323
Its working for me