# How to know why my app is not compatible with certain devices in Google Developer Console?

Tags: android, compatibility, device

I have an app in the Play Store and it is not compatible with certain devices, what i don't understand is why, for example, is compatible with certain models of Galaxy Note 2 and not with the others (also Galaxy Note 2). There is a way to know the reason? In the Google Developer Console appear as not compatible, but not why.

Comment: My main guess is that some of those devices (Note 2) have a newer Android version than others, and those with older versions doesn't match your AndroidManifest parameters.

Comment: In fact, the main problem is that in the manufacturer's web page I couldn't find the models that appears in the Console as not compatible. I have some other devices that are not compatible, not only samsung smartphones. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

WIthin the developer console, select the app, the select APK. This will show you why devices are excluded   [image]

Comment: I don't have manually excluded devices. If you select "See list" from the Supported devices option and then select "not compatible" a new list will appear. In these new list, only appear the name and model of the devices but not the reason for be not compatible. The main problem here is that most of these models are imposible to find in the manufacturer's web page. Anyone knows if it is possible to know the reason of the device's incompatibility from the Developers Console?

Answer (score 2):

Go to release management then -> Device catalog, and select any Unsupported device to show its details and you will see the reason why this device doesn't supported

[Android app is supported by 0 devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14020237/android-app-is-supported-by-0-devices)

Comment: Really ? And where ?

Comment: You need to expand the details and then click the link to see it on the devices catalog.