# App shows 0 devices supported in play store

Tags: android, google-play, apk, android-manifest, device

Uploaded the apk file to Google Play and says supported devices is 0. not sure why but have added manifest and build gradle below.Please can some tell me why this is.I am struggling to find an answer to this problem which is very frustrarting

Manifest,

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
         package="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs" >



         <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
        android:required="true" />
          <uses-feature
        android:name="android.software.leanback"
        android:required="true" />

         <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

                <meta-data
                    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                    android:resource="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.ButtonActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_button"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.SongActivityA"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_song" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.SongBActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_song_b" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.AdieuActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_adieu" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.BabesActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_babes" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.BabylonActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_babylon" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.BattleActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_battle" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.BloodRedActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_blood_red" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.SongCActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_song_c" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.CavillyActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_cavilly" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.SongDActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_song_d" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.DidiActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_didi" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.DrinkActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_drink" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.SongEActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_song_e" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.EnglishActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_english" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.SongFActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_song_f" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.FathomActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_fathom" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.FlowerActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_flower" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.FourCoachActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_four_coach" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.SongGActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_song_g" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.GallipoliActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_gallipoli" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.SongHActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_song_h" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.HowActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_how" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.SongIActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_song_i" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.IWillActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_iwill" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.SongLActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_song_l" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.LancashireActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_lancashire" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.LibActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_lib" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.SongMActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_song_m" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.MarchingActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_marching" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.MenOfActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_men_of" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.SongOActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_song_o" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.OverTheHillActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_over_the_hill" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.PaceActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_pace" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.SongPActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_song_p" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.MyFavActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_my_fav" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.ParcelActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_parcel" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.PaulActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_paul" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.PleasantActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_pleasant" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.PleaseActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_please" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.SongRActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_song_r" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.RisingActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_rising" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.RunActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_run" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.LittleActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_little" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.MenTyActivityActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_men_ty" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.MyfavRudeActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_myfav_rude" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.SongSActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_song_s" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.ScarActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_scar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.SpanActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_span" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.SwingActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_swing" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.SongTActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_song_t" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.SoweryActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_sowery" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.GendarmersActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_gendarmers" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.GrenadierssActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_grenadierss" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.BroomActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_broom" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.CadgwithActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_cadgwith" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.CuckooActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_cuckoo" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.DiggerActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_digger" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.FoolActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_fool" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.GoodActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_good" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.FranceActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_france" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.FisheryActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_fishery" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.SongKActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_song_k" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.KeeperActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_keeper" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.ManchesterActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_manchester" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.OwlActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_owl" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.RochesterActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_rochester" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.ShoalsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_shoals" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.TravellerActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_traveller" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.TwolitActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_twolit" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.TwoMagActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_two_mag" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.SongVActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_song_v" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.SearchResultsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_search_results" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.VicarActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_vicar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.SongWActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_song_w" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.WeBeActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_we_be" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.WhenActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_when" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.WasLadActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_was_lad" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.JonesActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_jones" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.WhenKingActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_when_king" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.WhipActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_whip" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.CockadeActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_cockade" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.WhiteTydActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_white_tyd" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.WildRoverActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_wild_rover" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.LassieGoActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_lassie_go" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.YourGunsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_your_guns" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs.WoadActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_woad" >
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />


    </application>

</manifest>

    Build gradle,

    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.songbook.noo.CampfireSongs"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 7
        versionName "1.1"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
     'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0 '
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:7.5.0'
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14020237/android-app-is-supported-by-0-devices

Comment: Is your app for AndroidTV?

Answer (score 0):

These lines:

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
    android:required="true" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.software.leanback"
    android:required="true" />
```

Imply that the device must support a touchscreen and must support Leanback (i.e., Android TV). However, there are no touchscreen Android TV devices, your app is compatible with no devices.

You probably want to either remove both of those lines (if you don't plan to support Android TV devices) or use

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
    android:required="false" />
```

And ensure you have at least one Activity that implements the leanback launcher intent-filter as per the [Get Started with TV guide](http://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/start.html):

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using:

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.software.leanback"
    android:required="true" />
```

But this freature is only available for AndroidTV, not on Android phones. Take a look at the [reference here about Leanback freature.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#FEATURE_LEANBACK) Since you're not using Leanback theme, i assume your app is not for Android TV, so  you have to remove this feature from your manifest.

As stated on Android TV apps guide:

> If you are developing an app that runs on mobile (phones, wearables, tablets, etc.) as well as Android TV, set the required attribute value to false. If you set the required attribute value to true, your app will run only on devices that use the Leanback UI.