# Android: 0 supported devices on Developer Console

Tags: android, android-manifest

I just uploaded my first app in Android Market, but Developer Console says that it is compatible with 0 devices ! I have searched the web for a solution but all I found where very specific answers to very specific questions so they did not help that much.

Here is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.gethelp" >
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.software.leanback"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/NoActionBar" >
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".EditMessage"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_edit_message"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog.NoActionBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SelectContacts"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_select_contacts"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".FetchAddressIntentService"
            android:exported="false" />

        <activity
            android:name=".Settings"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".HowToUse"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_how_to_use" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**UPDATE :**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"


    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.gethelp"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
}
```

Comment: please add your gradle build file.. And I´d think its this line `<uses-feature
        android:name="android.software.leanback"
        android:required="true" />` that causes the problem..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14020237/android-app-is-supported-by-0-devices

Comment: @SebastianWalla I updated my question