# Google Play - Zero supported Devices, Not able to find app

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest

I have published an app in google play - [Smart Eye - Intrusion Catch](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.click.rollingstone.click2)

The problem however is **developer console shows zero supported devices**. I am able to search my app in laptop but when **searching through any android mobile device i am not able to find my app**.

[image]

My manifest file look like this -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.click.rollingstone.click2" >
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="22" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2.full" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.camera" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_DEBUG_APP" />

    <!-- To access Google+ APIs: -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <!--
 To retrieve OAuth 2.0 tokens or invalidate tokens to disconnect a user. This disconnect
     option is required to comply with the Google+ Sign-In developer policies
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" /> <!-- To retrieve the account name (email) as part of sign-in: -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" /> <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/eye"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <receiver
            android:name=".Click2AdminReceiver"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.device_admin"
                android:resource="@xml/device_admin" />

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
                <action android:name="android.app.action.ACTION_PASSWORD_CHANGED" />
                <action android:name="android.app.action.ACTION_PASSWORD_FAILED" />
                <action android:name="android.app.action.ACTION_PASSWORD_SUCCEEDED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name=".MailManager" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".CameraView"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name=".AppInfo"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_app_info" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Any ideas on what is happening wrong here. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please check this solution its working for me http://stackoverflow.com/a/14020303/3392323

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The line

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2.full" />
```

is wrong - the feature name you might be looking for is "android.hardware.camera.level.full".

That said, do you need the capabilities of a FULL-level camera device (see docs for this [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#FEATURE_CAMERA_LEVEL_FULL))?
It means you want full support of the new camera2 API, with 30fps full-resolution capture, etc.

If you don't need this, then just remove this uses-feature line, or add android:required="false" to the line and fix the feature name.

Answer (score 2):

You are declaring via the uses-feature elements that you only run on devices that have all of the following:

- android.hardware.camera
- android.hardware.camera.autofocus
- android.hardware.camera2.full

camera2 is an API, and not a feature to be declared in the manifest, so you are declaring you must have something that no devices have.  Remove this line.

Answer (score -1):

I guess its for permission. There are many permissions.

Try remove unusable ones it will help. May be there are some permissions which not supported by any device play store checks and don't show any device