# Camera2api Not Supported On Any Device

Tags: android

I am trying to use the Camera2api in my app to do OpenCV stuff. When I build the app and manually test the apk, I can get it to work on my target device. However, when I publish to the app store, google says 0 devices are supported and will not let me over ride this.

I've isolated the problem by uploading to the store multiple times with android.hardware.camera2.full commented out. When it is commented, google shows that it can be used with every device. However, it does not work when its uncommented.

Here is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.vitrixhealth.datacollection">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2.full"/>
```

Is this a google problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where does android.hardware.camera2.full come from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48094952/where-does-android-hardware-camera2-full-come-from)