# app not showing on Android Google play but do show when browsing Google play from PC

Tags: android, google-play-services

Yesterday I published my first app on Google play.
I can find the app when searching Google play from PC (using Chrome)
but when I search Google play from my Android cellphone it is not found.

After reading some posts having the same issue I changed the app name to be more unique but still I cannot find it on my Android cellphone Google play.

Any idea of why the app is found when browsing Google play from PC and not found when searching Google play from my cellphone device ?

EDIT:
app manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="it.co.boom.acc_aid">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2.full" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/accident"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <activity android:name=".getOfficeID"></activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: its because of different routing and google cdn update delay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my 2 cents. There can be multiple possibilities.

1- Apps are not shown on devices which don't support them. Please check your manifest xml file. Maybe its some specific features that you have stated mandatory there and is not available on your device, or maybe its the minimum supported OS version etc. Here is how you can see from Play console which devices are in the exclusion list : [View & restrict your app's compatible devices](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7353455?hl=en). Quoting from [uses-feature](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element)

> Google Play uses the elements declared in your app manifest to filter your app from devices that do not meet its hardware and software feature requirements.
>
> By specifying the features that your application requires, you enable Google Play to present your application only to users whose devices meet the application's feature requirements, rather than presenting it to all users.

2- It takes some time for the changes to propagate. You can try clearing your cache / data of Google Play app and then try searching.

---

**Update**

From the manifest you shared I can see you declared the following:

> `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2.full" />`

without using `android:required` attribute. From the documentation of [android:required](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element#required) attribute:

> The default value for android:required if not declared is "true".

This means if a device doesn't have this feature, it will not be a supported device and won't show the app on Play store app on the device. That's probably what's happening. Check the following answer on the question [Google Play - Zero supported Devices, Not able to find app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33181658/1306419). It might help fix your issue.

Comment: 1. I ran the app on my device so I guess device is supported.
2. I'll wait.
Thanks

Comment: If you share your manifest, we can see if that&#39;s the case or not. It only tells play store to not show it on unsupported devices on play store. If you run it on debug mode, it will still run. Just double check

Comment: I've added the link in answer with more info on that

Comment: I have added the manifest to my post. I followed the instructions in link you shared and it shows 0 (zero) **SUPPORTED DEVICES**, can't figure why.

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 possible things it can possibly be.

1. check the os version of the mobile and the minimum version of the APK if your mobile os is between the supported range you should see it.
2. Check the region where you published the app, is it for a specific country/location. you may not see the app that is not published in your region.
3. Check if an app requires any mandatory features which your mobile doesn't support. Eg: Apps with camera feature required will not be visible on android phones without a camera.