# Signed apk has 0 compatibility in google play store

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, compatibility, build.gradle, google-play-developer-api

I've been working on a project for some time now and I pretty much finished and am ready to release it to the play store. I was able to deploy my app through debug mode via the USB cable onto my Samsung s4 phone. Strangely, when I generated the signed apk and released it to the play store, I can't download it on my phone... This makes no sense since I was able to use it when I was testing it... I asked my friends and they experienced the same thing. I looked at my developer console and it says my app is compatible with LITERALLY 0 phones in the market... So I looked it up and I thought maybe my manifest is messed up, so here it is (I'm using android studio btw):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="XXXX">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.CAMERA"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
    >
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>
    <activity
        android:name="XXXX"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />

    <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges=
            "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />

    <provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProviderXXXX"
        android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
        android:exported="true" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

So I see no issues in the manifest (maybe someone can correct me on that) and if there were it wouldn't have ran on my phone when I tested the app.

So I use a lot of external libraries for my app, here is the list:

1) facebook api
2) twitter api
3) snapdragon
4) google play service

I also had to use multidex (as you saw in the manifest) because the code exceeded 64k lines of code. Here's how the build.gradle looks like:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "xxxx"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 3
    versionName "1.2"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
sourceSets { main { java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java', 'libs'] } }
 }

 repositories {
     mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
 }

 dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
    compile('com.twitter.sdk.android:tweet-composer:1.0.2@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
 }
```

I'm totally new with gradle so I'm not sure if it's set up correctly so there maybe issues with the gradle itself or maybe something else. Anyone have any suggestions what I can do?

Comment: 1st you can try changing the `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.CAMERA"/>` line to `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>`. By default the value is true. So all devices with no camera won't appear there. Also checkout answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14020237/android-app-is-supported-by-0-devices

Comment: A small question, are you use same keystore in both ``Release`` and ``Debug`` mode. If not, you can't install 1 app with 2 keystore.

Comment: I just do release. I don't sign for debug...

Comment: you could edit this question down to the essential elements. now that you've solved the issue, it makes sense to eliminate all the noise about stuff that wasn't related to the real problem you were having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the camera feature to required false in the manifest and that did the trick. When I uploaded the apk in the developer console it said 8k+ devices supported. Also the manifest was inccorect, when you put the use-features tag make sure to have camera all lowercase not uppercase like I had.

Comment: Even though it now supports iver 8k+ devices I still can't download it on my samsung s4 device and I see on my developer console that samsung s4 is on the list for supported devices for my app....emailed google about this....