# Supported Devices 0 shown on Google Play Developer Console

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

I am facing a problem as my app already on play store with eclipse compiled APK and I am building new APK with Android Studio, when I want to upload the same on Google Play it is showing 0 Supported Devices. I don't know why, I searched everywhere and I changed my code according to that but also I am facing the same problem. Please suggest me any solution regarding the same.

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.handygo.rockasap"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="68"
    android:versionName="4.3.1" >

    <!-- android:maxSdkVersion="17" max version create problem in Reader -->
   <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="22"></uses-sdk>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_STATS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <!-- <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" /> -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />



    <uses-permission android:name="com.handygo.rockasap.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />


    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location.network"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="true" >
    </uses-feature>

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true"></uses-feature>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.samsung.android.providers.context.permission.WRITE_USE_APP_FEATURE_SURVEY" />

    <application
        tools:replace="android:icon, android:label, android:name, android:theme"
        android:name="com.handygo.rockasap.RockstandApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >

        <!-- MOBIKWIK Activity Files -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.mobikwik.sdk.MobikwikSDK"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="MobiKwik"
            android:theme="@style/MKSDKTransparent"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        </activity>
        <!-- PayTM Activity -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.paytm.pgsdk.PaytmPGActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mobikwik.sdk.PGWebView"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="BankPage"
            android:theme="@style/MKSDKTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mobikwik.sdk.PaymentOptions"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/MKSDKTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mobikwik.sdk.PaymentActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/MKSDKTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.mobikwik.sdk.GetUserDetailsActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/MKSDKTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >
        </activity>

        <!-- multiwindow code -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.samsung.android.sdk.multiwindow.enable"
            android:value="true" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.samsung.android.sdk.multiwindow.multiinstance.enable"
            android:value="true" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.sec.android.multiwindow.STYLE"
            android:value="fixedRatio" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.sec.android.support.multiwindow"
            android:value="true" />

        <service android:name="com.handygo.rockasap.utils.GCMIntentService" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.handygo.rockasap.utils.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.handygo.rockasap" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <provider
            android:name="com.handygo.rockasap.DataProvider"
            android:authorities="com.handygo.rockasap.DataProvider"
            android:exported="true"
            android:multiprocess="true" >
        </provider>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.crash.FixBooksDirectoryActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:process=":crash"
            android:theme="@style/FBReader.Dialog" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.fbreader.action.CRASH" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:scheme="CachedCharStorageException" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.crash.MissingNativeLibraryActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:process=":crash"
            android:theme="@style/FBReader.Dialog" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.fbreader.action.CRASH" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

                <data android:scheme="ExceptionInInitializerError" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.api.ApiService"
            android:exported="false"
            android:launchMode="singleTask" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.fbreader.action.API" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <activity
            android:name="com.artifex.mupdfdemo.ScreenShotsActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.SpeakActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.Panel" />
        <activity
            tools:replace="android:icon, android:label, android:name, android:theme"
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.FBReader"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
            tools:node="remove"
            android:label="Rockstand"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:theme="@style/FBReader.Activity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.DictionaryBrowser" />
        <activity
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.CancelActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:theme="@style/FBReader.Dialog" />
        <activity
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.style.StyleListActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:theme="@style/FBReader.Dialog" />
        <activity
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.style.EditStyleActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:theme="@style/FBReader.Dialog" />
        <activity
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.image.ImageViewActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:theme="@style/FBReader.Activity" />
        <!-- android:process=":imageView" -->
        <service
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.libraryService.LibraryService"
            android:exported="false"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:process=":libraryService" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.fbreader.action.LIBRARY_SERVICE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <activity
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.library.BookInfoActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:process=":library"
            android:theme="@style/FBReader.Activity" />
        <activity
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.library.LibrarySearchActivity"
            android:process=":library"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.library.LibraryActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:process=":library"
            android:theme="@style/FBReader.Activity" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
                android:value="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.library.LibrarySearchActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.TOCActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:theme="@style/FBReader.Activity" />
        <activity
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.BookmarksActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:theme="@style/FBReader.Activity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.BookmarkEditActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:theme="@style/FBReader.Dialog" />
        <activity
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.preferences.PreferenceActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:theme="@style/FBReader.Activity" />
        <activity
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.preferences.EditBookInfoActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:process=":library"
            android:theme="@style/FBReader.Activity" />
        <activity
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.network.BookDownloader"
            android:process=":networkLibrary"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" >
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.network.BookDownloaderService"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:process=":networkLibrary" />

        <activity
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.network.NetworkSearchActivity"
            android:process=":networkLibrary"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.searchable"
                android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.network.NetworkLibraryPrimaryActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:process=":networkLibrary"
            android:theme="@style/FBReader.Activity" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.network.NetworkLibrarySecondaryActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:process=":networkLibrary"
            android:theme="@style/FBReader.Activity" />
        <activity
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.network.AuthenticationActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:process=":networkLibrary"
            android:theme="@style/FBReader.Dialog" />
        <activity
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.network.BuyBooksActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:process=":networkLibrary"
            android:theme="@style/FBReader.Dialog" />
        <activity
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.network.AddCatalogMenuActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:process=":networkLibrary"
            android:theme="@style/FBReader.Dialog" />
        <activity
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.network.AddCustomCatalogActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:process=":networkLibrary"
            android:theme="@style/FBReader.Dialog" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.network.AuthorizationMenuActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:process=":networkLibrary"
            android:theme="@style/FBReader.Dialog" />
        <activity
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.network.TopupMenuActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:process=":networkLibrary"
            android:theme="@style/FBReader.Dialog" />
        <activity
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.network.NetworkBookInfoActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:process=":networkLibrary"
            android:theme="@style/FBReader.Activity" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.artifex.mupdfdemo.MuPDFActivity"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" >
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name="org.geometerplus.android.fbreader.network.ListenerCallback"
            android:process=":networkLibrary" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.fbreader.action.network.SIGNIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <activity
            android:name=".FragmentScreenActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.MULTIWINDOW_LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="NewGCMLandingActivity" >
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.handygo.rockasap.TransparentActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent" >
        </activity>


        <!-- The authenticator service -->
        <service
            android:name="com.handygo.rockasap.services.AuthenticationService"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator"
                android:resource="@xml/authenticator" />
        </service>
        <service android:name="com.handygo.rockasap.services.RockstandService" />
        <service android:name="com.handygo.rockasap.services.DownloadNotifactionService" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.handygo.rockasap.services.ReferralReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:permission="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver 
            android:name="com.handygo.rockasap.UpdatePaymentSuccess">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="update_paytm" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    jcenter{
        url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
    }
}
dependencies {

    provided fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile ('com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.+') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'multidex'
    }
    compile files('libs/multiwindow-v1.2.6.jar')
    compile files('libs/PGSDK_v1.0.jar')
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    compile 'com.flurry.android:analytics:6.2.0'

    compile(project(':FBReader')) {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'multidex'
    }
    compile(project(':mobikwiksdk')) {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'multidex'
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
    compile ('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'){
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'multidex'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    compileOptions.encoding = 'ISO-8859-1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.handygo.rockasap"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 68
        versionName "4.3.1"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    }
    dexOptions{
        preDexLibraries = false
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }

        main {
            java {
                exclude 'org/apache/http/ConnectionClosedException.class'
            }
        }
        // Move the tests to tests/java, tests/res, etc...
        instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

        // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
        // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
        // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/... which would
        // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
        // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
        // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }   
}
```

**Project Structure:**
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Please, check my answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32607502/2298241

I hope this could help you.