# Google play shows 0 device support

Tags: android

Google play shows 0 device supported. I have included possible missing features required false. My manifest look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myapp.managermobile">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.chefonline.managermobile.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.chefonline.managermobile.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.microphone"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.location.network"
        android:required="false" />

    <application
        android:name="com.myapp.singleton.HttpRequestQueue"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme">

        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="fdsfdslkfjsdlflds" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.myapp.activity.SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.myapp.activity.myappActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_dash_board" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.myapp.activity.CustomRangeActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_custom_range" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.myapp.activity.OrderDetailsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_order_details">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.myapp.activity.myappActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.myapp.activity.CustomerInfoActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_customer_info" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.myapp.activity.ResetPasswordActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_dash_board_reset_password" />
        <activity android:name="com.myapp.activity.ChangePincodeActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.myapp.activity.SettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_settings" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.myapp.activity.AdminSettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_admin_settings" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.myapp.activity.PrinterSettingsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_kitchen_copy" />
        <activity android:name="com.myapp.activity.EndOfDayActivity"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.myapp.activity.CallbackSupportActivity"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.myapp.activity.OffersListActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_offers_list"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.myapp.activity.AddChangeOffersActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_add_offer"></activity>
        <activity android:name="com.myapp.activity.ReservationDetailsActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name="com.myapp.activity.AllReservationsActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name="com.myapp.activity.ReservationSettingsActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name="com.myapp.activity.RestaurantListActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name="com.myapp.activity.RestaurantSearchActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name="com.myapp.activity.MapActivity"></activity>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.myapp.gcm.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>

                <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

                <category android:name="com.chefonline.srsmyapp" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.myapp.alarm.AlarmReceiver">
            <intent-filter>

                <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
                <action android:name="com.chefonline.srsmyapp.ALARM" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="com.myapp.alarm.OrderRefreshService" />
        <service android:name="com.myapp.gcm.GcmIntentService" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.myapp.activity.myappTodayActivityMain"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_dash_board_today"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.myapp.activity.myappActivity" />
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.myapp.activity.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_splash" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.myapp.activity.MessageActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_message"
            android:theme="@style/MyMaterialTheme"></activity>

        <service
            android:name="com.myapp.services.SignalRService"
            android:enabled="true" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

But still showing 0 devices support. Please any one give me suggestion

[image]

My Gradle is

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        //applicationId "com.myapp.managermobile"
        applicationId "com.myapp.srsdashboard"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 13
        versionName "1.2.3"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile files('libs/android-query.0.26.8.jar')
    compile files('libs/picasso-2.2.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/signalr-client-sdk.jar')
    compile files('libs/signalr-client-sdk-android.jar')
    compile files('libs/gson-2.3.1.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.roughike:bottom-bar:1.2.1'
}
```

Comment: Can you add your build.gradle?

Comment: I have updated post with gradle file. Please have a look

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.location"
    android:required="false" />
```

as you have it twice.

Possible other issues can be found here: [Android app is supported by 0 devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14020237/android-app-is-supported-by-0-devices)

Comment: Did you try to remove all permissions and features as well? (App won't work, but just to check if it's an issue of permissions/features)

Comment: i have tried with removing all features but still it doesnt work. My previous version is fine in this new version i have implemented signalR. after that  i am facing this type of problem

Comment: Maybe you added some library?