# Can't install beta app from Play Store on the same device that was used for development

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest

I have uploaded my app to Google Play, and I see the “**your device isn't compatible with this version**” message. I have seen many other similar question, but my case seems to be unique: I get this message on the very same device that I have used for development.

Here is my **manifest** file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="io.mindworks.foodforyou">

    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" android:required="false" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" android:required="false" />

    <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="false"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name=".ui.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.SplashActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_splash"
            android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ui.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"/>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="xxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxxx"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Update**

For those who say I can not be a beta tester for my own application:
[image: Tester]

And here is the error message:
[image: ErrorMessage]

Comment: are you getting same message on other device ?

Comment: yes, with the few I have tried ...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found the answer here:
[Android app is supported by 0 devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14020237/android-app-is-supported-by-0-devices/32607502#32607502)

> Sometimes the reason for this is a third party library that you have
>   referenced. If you can find which one is it and if you can remove it
>   you can solve the problem.
>
> In may case I had to remove:
>
> > org.apache.commons.io:2.4

by Ivo Stoyanov

Answer (score -1):

you want be able to use that application in developer account means you will not be able to install beta application on that device with same account.

developer account should not be same as that in device to install beta app.

try that with using different account.

check [setup Alpha/Beta test](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en)

Comment: This is definitely not true. I have did that before with other applications.

Comment: I did set up a beta test. Please quote the part that says that I can't use the same device/account for beta testing.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use the same account for Beta testing as the developer account. The same account usage is permissible for Alpha testing but using the same developer account for Beta testing violates the definition of Beta testing in itself so, you are not allowed to Beta test your apps using the same account as it's developer.

Comment: I do not think so. I really don't understand why I could not be a beta tester for my own app. Please quote the part from Google Developer that states it.