# 0 Supported Devices on Google play

Tags: android, android-manifest, device

Supported Devices 0 on google play store,
Here is my Manifest file. Please help me with this guys. There are lot of questions about this but still i couldn't find a solution for this. I think my case is different.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera2"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".NameActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MainNavigation"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main_navigation"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
    <activity
        android:name=".News"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_news"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Settings"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_settings"
        android:parentActivityName=".News">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.chathu.ranga.network.News" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".ShareActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_share"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
    <activity
        android:name=".SendSMS"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_send_sms"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"></activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android app is supported by 0 devices](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14020237/android-app-is-supported-by-0-devices)

Answer (score 1):

Just change this

```
<uses-feature
android:name="android.hardware.camera2"
android:required="true" />
```

to the one below

```
<uses-feature
android:name="android.hardware.camera2"
android:required="false" />
```

This might help you solve your problem