# Amazon says no device supported for android app

Tags: android, publish, amazon-appstore

i want to publish my android app on amazon but it gives me the error "No device supported". i have defined the minSdkLevel in manifest file.
please give me any solution for that. Here is manifest file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.android.abc"
    android:versionName="1.2.1"
    android:versionCode="4">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission                                                  android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"/>

.
.
.
.
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To help give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Could you also post your Manifest?

Comment: @MichaelDodd you can see it in the edited post

Comment: @AsadMahmood Use this link to test your apk. https://developer.amazon.com/app-testing-service .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had some issues regarding this on the play and when I was searching for suggestions came across [Android app is supported by 0 devices](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32749726/174777) that saved my day. Maybe it will help you too.