# Android Developer console shows zero supported devices

Tags: android, google-play

I've been trying to figure out this issue for a couple of days, but haven't found any solution yet. There is no `uses-feature` element that restricts the device in the manifest.

These are the permissions used in `Manifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Here is the build config in `app.gradle`:

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.XXXXX"
    minSdkVersion 12
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 2
    versionName "1.0.1"
}
```

and the app is using following dependencies:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile files('libs/diewald_shapeFileReader.jar')
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
compile 'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.9'
compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'
compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.lang:2.6'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.2'
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14020303/7320259 please try this

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/twrjOKKE27o

Comment: post your full manifest and gradle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to replace these dependencies

```
compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'
compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.lang:2.6'
```

with

```
compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
compile 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6'
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 4):

It has to do something with this https://github.com/robot-mitya/rosjava_bootstrap/commit/f9acae776f991374428100f8193c5f3861ca9514

Change this

```
 compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.io:2.4'
 compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.lang:2.6'
```

to

```
  compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4' 
  compile 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6'
```

Please check if this works.

Similar issue https://stackoverflow.com/a/32749726/3111083

Comment: Don't use org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4. replace it with compile 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6'