# App showing incompatible with the device I developed it on in play store

Tags: android, android-manifest

The reason given by a play support agent is :
"I've also found your app is not compatible with the Micromax Yurenka S due to a conflict in your app's manifest with the following:

No supported native platform:arm64-v8a, armeabi, armeabi-v7a"

I am pasting my manifest file below:

Can someone just point me what I am doing wrong.

```
<!-- Permissions for the app start -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <permission android:name="com.mypackage.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.mypackage.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <!-- Permissions for the app end -->
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/NoActionBarTheme">
        <receiver android:name="com.mixpanel.android.mpmetrics.GCMReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="com.mypackage" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <!-- Bugsnag api key start -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.bugsnag.android.API_KEY"
            android:value="5b9b5215b476a9a2c83c22f7bd62beb6" />
        <!-- Bugsnag api key end -->
        <activity android:name=".Controllers.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Controllers.SplashActivity"
            android:theme="@style/NoActionBarTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Controllers.SelectionActivity"
            android:theme="@style/NoActionBarTheme" />
        <activity android:name=".Controllers.LoginActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Controllers.SignUpStep1Activity" />
        <activity android:name=".Controllers.ForgotPasswordActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Controllers.ForgotMembershipNumberActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Controllers.VerifyOtpActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Controllers.MobNoChangedActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Controllers.GetStartedActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Controllers.ForgotPasswordStep2Activity" />
        <activity android:name=".Controllers.ForgotPasswordStep3Activity" />
        <activity android:name=".Controllers.EventsListActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Controllers.EventsDetailActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Controllers.ProfileDetailActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Controllers.AnnouncementListActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Controllers.AnnouncementDetailActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Controllers.WebviewActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".Controllers.MemberDirectoryListActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />
        <activity android:name=".Controllers.MemberDirectoryDetailActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Controllers.IdCardActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Controllers.EditProfileActivity" />

        <activity android:name=".Controllers.ChangePasswordActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:name="com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImageActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Base.Theme.AppCompat"/>
    </application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atlast found the issue after spending 2 days. Check the post for more details. I am posting the answer for someone who might come in future. [Android app is supported by 0 devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14020237/android-app-is-supported-by-0-devices)

Check your build.gradle file - if you see something like:

```
compile 'org.apache.directory.studio:org.apache.commons.codec:1.+'
```

change it to:

```
compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.+'
```