# Playstore: "0 devices supported" for app made in Android Studio manifest and

Tags: android, google-play, manifest, device, compatibility

Our Android Release on Playstore is showing 0 devices supported. I've looked and searched stackoverflow but couldn't find a solution.  Have tried to eliminate conflicts but just can't seem to identify what is causing it to break for all devices, something really fundamental that I might be missing.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.nearlaw.lawyer.lawyerprofile">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera2"
    android:required="true"
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA2" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="NearLaw"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <receiver android:name=".UninstalIntentReceiver">
        <intent-filter android:priority="0">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUERY_PACKAGE_RESTART" />

            <data android:scheme="package" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity android:name=".SplashScreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Login" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="Basic Info">

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SignIn2of6"
        android:label="Address Info">

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SignIn3of6"
        android:label="Professional Info">

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SignIn4of6"
        android:label="Practice Area">

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SignIn5of6"
        android:label="Accesibility" />
    <activity android:name=".SignIn6of6" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Profile"
        android:label="Profile">

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".TabLayoutTest"
        android:label="Consulting">

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Trans">

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".TabTest"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_tab_test"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".TabTest1"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_tab_test1"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity android:name=".Speach" />
    <activity android:name=".Image_Upload" />
    <activity android:name=".Policy" />
    <activity android:name=".ProfileView" />
    <activity android:name=".EditProfile" />
    <activity android:name=".TestTabhost" />
    <activity android:name=".SpinnerTest" />
    <activity android:name=".Slot" />
    <activity android:name=".SlotLayout" />
    <activity
        android:name=".HomePage"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_home_page"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".NewHome"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_new_home"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".confirmOtp"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name=".UserProfile" />
    <activity android:name=".ProfileSelect" />
    <activity android:name=".Register" />
    <activity android:name=".ViewProfile" />
    <activity android:name=".Forgot" />
    <activity android:name=".forgotOtp" />
    <activity android:name=".updatePass" />
    <activity
        android:name=".eJudgement"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_e_judgement"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
    <activity
        android:name=".AdvanceSearch"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Main2Activity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme1" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Main3Activity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme1" />
    <activity
        android:name=".FullJudgement"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme1" />
    <activity android:name=".Policy2" />
    <activity android:name=".SignIn6of61" />
    <activity android:name=".SignIn6of62" />
    <activity android:name=".SignIn6of63" />
    <activity android:name=".LoginOrSIgnUp" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Contact"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme1" />
    <activity
        android:name=".TermsAndConditions"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme1" />
    <activity
        android:name=".AboutUs"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme1" />
</application>
<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true" />

</manifest>
```

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.nearlaw.lawyer.lawyerprofile"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 3
    versionName "1.01"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
    }
}
android {
    aaptOptions.cruncherEnabled = false
    aaptOptions.useNewCruncher = false
}

android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    lintOptions {
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
        }

    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
android {
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
}
compile project(':library')

//bottom bar act main 3

compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.+'
compile 'com.google.zxing:core:3.2.1'
compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.1'
compile 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.2.0@aar'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:10.0.1'
compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:5.1.1'
compile 'com.squareup.dagger:dagger:1.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.1'
compile 'com.borjabravo:readmoretextview:2.0.1'
compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.1.+'
compile 'org.elasticsearch.client:rest:5.4.0'
compile 'com.ms-square:expandableTextView:0.1.4'
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: I would suggest to remove "supports-screens" from AndroidManifest.xml since you set everything to true... Some items like "supports-screens" are deprecated... At least for test.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14020237/android-app-is-supported-by-0-devices

Comment: W0rmH0le I tried to remove that and then do a clear build, still returns the same error "0 devices supported". Any other ideas, anyone?

Answer (score 0):

You have a wrong  tag:

```
<uses-feature
android:name="android.hardware.camera2"
android:required="true"
android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
/>
```

You need to change it to the following:

```
<!-- This is for API below 21 -->
<uses-permission android:required="true" android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />

<!-- This is for API >= 21 -->
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2.full" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2.autofocus" />

<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
```