# There is only one supported device at play.google.com Device catalog

Tags: android

There are similar titles like "zero devices compatible" or "one device compatible". But problems are different for all of them.

How can i fix it?

## AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.appdevelopment.myapp">

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.software.leanback"
    android:required="true" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
    android:required="false" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning,MissingTvBanner">

    <receiver android:name="com.appdevelopment.myapp.MyAppWidget">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/myapp_widget_info" />
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name="com.appdevelopment.myapp.MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

It is a simple countdown widget app

## app gradle :

I think everything is normal here.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.appdevelopment.myapp"
    minSdkVersion 17
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Supported devices : 1 supported by this app
All devices : 12,501 total

Comment: It is not about app stores. There is a problem with ANdroidManifest.xml

Comment: None  of answers in this link answers my question. If it is a "dupe" then show me the correct answer which solves this problem

Comment: are you sure you did this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/48628062/1843331

Comment: @Zoe I totally disagree.

Comment: which device is supported one? Let's find what is so special about it.

Comment: If feature "android.software.leanback" is required, the app will run on Android TV only. [Docs](https://developer.android.com/training/tv/start/start#leanback-req)