# Android app is supported by 0 devices suddenly

Tags: java, android, google-play, android-manifest, google-play-console

**My app is suddenly showing supported devices in play console as 0.**

I did some googling, found a few similar questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14020237/android-app-is-supported-by-0-devices) but none of the solutions worked for me.

**Below is my AndroidManifest:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:dist="http://schemas.android.com/apk/distribution"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.demo.android">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />

<application
    android:name=".Demo"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


    <activity
        android:name=".ui.home.HomeActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="demo.com/app"
                android:scheme="https" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".ui.splash.SplashActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Launcher">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

**Below are some screenshots from play console:**
[image: One]
[image: Two]

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: What is your targetSdkVersion?

Answer (score 1):

This is usually due to a permission or uses-feature tag being added but that is not a valid value. It's not obvious from what you shared what is wrong though. Some SDKs you depend on can bring additional permissions.

You can try running with the APK you upload:

```
aapt dump xmltree app.apk AndroidManifest.xml
```

or if you upload an App Bundle:

```
bundletool dump manifest --bundle app.aab
```

And double-check the permissions and the uses-feature tags.

Answer (score 0):

check minSdkVersion in gradle 
maybe you select minSdkVersion very high like 28