# Play store error : app is supported by 0 devices

Tags: android

**This is my Manifest file**
Please find solution for the above error

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MICROPHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android app is supported by 0 devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14020237/android-app-is-supported-by-0-devices)

Answer (score 0):

`android.hardware.camera2` is a [package name](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary), not a feature name.

The name of the hardware feature for a rear-facing camera is `android.hardware.camera`, or `android.hardware.camera.any` for any camera.  See [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element#hw-features) for a list of all the camera-related feature names.

If you require the `android.hardware.camera2` API, you should ensure that your minimum SDK version is set to at least `21`.

Comment: Yes. I have added android:required="false" to camera2. Because if do not write any requirement by default its value is true. and It's there in the Developer site.

Comment: @SonaliKamble Note that `camera2` is not listed on the developer site as a feature.