# My app not available on google play for Samsung Galaxy Y, Galyxy mini (2.3.6)

Tags: android, google-play

I've published an app in Google Play Store. The App is not available in Samsung galaxy Y, Mini. This my manifest.xml

```
 <uses-sdk
    android:maxSdkVersion="19"
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" android:required="false" />
<permission android:name="my.package.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="my.package.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: Well, api 7 is 2.1 android. 2.3 android can support c2d. Nowt wrong there. Screen sizes maybe? Do you support small screens?

Answer (score 2):

On named devices there is no Autofocus Manifest Permission useable.

```
"android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
```

try to add

```
"android.hardware.camera"
```

instead. This should make your app shown in Google Play on Galaxy Y, ...

Answer (score 0):

This might be a similar question. Basically, if you have a large apk (30-50MB+), some devices don't support it due to a partition cache size limit.

More information on this question:
[Why does the Google Play store say my Android app is incompatible with my own device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10475954/why-does-the-google-play-store-say-my-android-app-is-incompatible-with-my-own-de)