# Google Play Dev Console always show no compatible device

Tags: android, google-play

This is my first time to upload my app to Google Play Store, but I found and issue about "no compatible device". I think that I've covered all requirement in the manifest file. My app require some simple things, my app must be able to run in the range of API 9 to API 20. Here is my manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="kolek.com.kolekin" >

<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true" />

<compatible-screens>
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="normal" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="ldpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="mdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="hdpi" />
    <screen android:screenSize="xlarge" android:screenDensity="xhdpi" />

    <screen android:screenSize="large" android:screenDensity="213" />
</compatible-screens>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Theme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Login"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".Register"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="Register">
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="Kolek.in">
    </activity>

    <!--<activity android:name=".GroupLists"-->
        <!--android:screenOrientation="portrait"-->
        <!--android:label="Group Data">-->
    <!--</activity>-->

    <activity android:name=".GroupData"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="Data">
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".GroupDetail"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="Group Detail">
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".ShowMap"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="Map">
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".AddItem"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="Add Item">
    </activity>

    <activity android:name=".SavedItem"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="Saved Items"/>

    <activity android:name=".Profile"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="Profil"/>

    <activity android:name=".About"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:label="Tentang"/>
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.Camera" android:required="true"/>
```

Am I miss something?
NOTE : I'm using Android Studio so the minSdkVersion etc placed in app.gradle file. Thank you.

Comment: I haven't used Gradle as such but what if you add one small line here in manifest  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />

Comment: @MOSO I finally changed the camera requirement to `false` and the Dev Console showing supported devices, I just consider why this is happen. Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: Hmmm...saw that. Google does not allow devices with false compatibility. i  waved around a bit here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10475954/why-does-the-google-play-store-say-my-android-app-is-incompatible-with-my-own-de hope you too have checked if nt go through it. Sometimes Google really want to make us work :p interviews our patience.. :D

Comment: Well, thank you anyway. One more question, do you know how long the expected waiting time for the app to be appear while searching it on my devices?

Comment: It may take approx 5-30 mins however it may exceed depending on the Google as of whole coz it took around 2 hours once in my case still better than iOS hah they take 2-3 weeks. :P

Comment: Oke thank you, after waiting several hours, now my app is searchable in Play Store.

Answer (score 0):

No need to add both supports-screens and compatible-screens. Any one would do.

Also if your camera is not mandatory then set that required field to false, also you should have

`uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />`  in your manifest.

Other than this I didn't see any other issues

Comment: do you how long the estimated time for the to be appear in google play store from devices after submission process?