# Android app not compatible with Moto E?

Tags: android, google-maps, opengl-es-2.0, motorola

I have an Android application min API = 16

**For almost everything I put required = false**

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.memories.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.UNINSTALL_SHORTCUT" />

<uses-permission android:name="com.traveljar.memories.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />


<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT"
    android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.HARDWARE_CONTROLS"
    android:protectionLevel="normal"
    android:required="false" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="false" />
```

**Still the app is not compatible with Moto E**. For others (I have tested with minimum atleast 15 different hadsets, it is compatible)

Screenshots : 
[IMG]http://i64.tinypic.com/sbqa9y.jpg[/IMG] 
[IMG]http://i68.tinypic.com/zlw1p2.jpg[/IMG]

Comment: What other `<uses-feature>` and `<uses-permission>` tags do you have?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice updated my code

Comment: @Code-Apprentice [IMG]http://i64.tinypic.com/sbqa9y.jpg[/IMG]

Comment: @Code-Apprentice [IMG]http://i68.tinypic.com/zlw1p2.jpg[/IMG]

Comment: Do you have enough permission to add those images directly to your question?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I think so. Let me do it.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Hey any pointers? Not able to solve it still.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a country restriction that is setup in your Google Play Pricing and Distribution section.  If it is not that it may be that the size of your app is larger than the device's cache partition.

See: [Why does the Google Play store say my Android app is incompatible with my own device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10475954/why-does-the-google-play-store-say-my-android-app-is-incompatible-with-my-own-de/)