# Play Store says app is incompatible with phone tested on

Tags: java, android, google-play

The Play Store says that my app is incompatible with all the devices that I have, but that also includes the phone that I tested it on. Below is my Manifest file. I tested it on my Nexus 5X running Nougat, but the Play Store says that the app is incompatible with that phone of mine. Thanks a lot !

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.health4everyone.thejdeep.healthpal">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="#####" />

        <activity android:name="com.heath4everyone.thejdeep.healthpal.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.heath4everyone.thejdeep.healthpal.Home"></activity>

        <activity android:name="com.heath4everyone.thejdeep.healthpal.Hospitals"></activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.heath4everyone.thejdeep.healthpal.Restaurants"
            android:label="Map">
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.heath4everyone.thejdeep.healthpal.ActivityTracker"></activity>

        <activity   android:name=".Settings" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.health4everyone.thejdeep.healthpal.Settings" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.heath4everyone.thejdeep.healthpal.SearchFoodByRestaurant"
            android:label="Search Restaurant">
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Edit : Removed the API key :)

Comment: what's the overall size of your app?  Perhaps this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10475954/why-does-the-google-play-store-say-my-android-app-is-incompatible-with-my-own-de?rq=1

Comment: Size of the app is 5MB, so I do not think its the size issue

Comment: Don't just focus on the accepted answer as there are about 6 other solutions listed there you may want to investigate.