# How to tell why a device isn't compatible in the Google Play store

Tags: android, google-play, compatibility

I have an app published to the Google Play store. I can deploy to the device (Google Pixel running Pie) without issue through Android Studio, but when I go to the page for the app (same version) that is published in the store, it says my device is not compatible.

This is frustrating because 1) the app works perfectly fine when I install it through Android Studio and 2) the play store gives me no feedback as to why my device is allegedly incompatible.

I've tried clearing the Google Play Store cache multiple times as I've seen suggested. However, this issue seems to affect other devices on Android 8+ and I have no clue as to why.

Is there any way to get feedback from Google as to why a device is incompatible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does the Google Play store say my Android app is incompatible with my own device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10475954/why-does-the-google-play-store-say-my-android-app-is-incompatible-with-my-own-de)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out you can view all incompatible devices and why they are incompatible in the Google Play console by going to `Release management -> Device catalog`.

Comment: For us this did not list any excluded devices, even though users reported seeing the error. If this is the case, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62326358/1822977

Answer (score -1):

You need to set up a device catalog in your google play console.
Go to **Google play console-> reach and devices-> Device Catalogue.**

Click on **Manage Devices> Exclude Devices**.
Check all the Devices you want to exclude.

Unfortunately, you can only exclude devices by a single device at a time. For example, you cannot exclude all TV or all watches in one go.

[image]