# "This app is incompatible with all of your devices" after upload apk on Google Play

Tags: android

After upload my app on Google Play. I receive "This app is incompatible with all of your devices" from Google Play.

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" package="com.mducc.camrealtime">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2.full" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.ml.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
            android:value="ocr" />
        <activity android:name=".ui.Cam2RealTimeActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ui.ModeActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does the Google Play store say my Android app is incompatible with my own device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10475954/why-does-the-google-play-store-say-my-android-app-is-incompatible-with-my-own-de)

Comment: Could you also add your build.gradle for the module? The target SDK version is usually configured there. Also will need to know what version of Android your devices are running. I'm guessing that the minSdkVersion is getting set to something high, like version 28 or something.

Comment: The included AndroidManifest is the one you have defined, however the resulting Manifest can include more entries e.g. from used libraries. Use the Analyze APK feature of Android Studio to extract the real AndroidManifest.xml content of your app.

Comment: minSdkVersion is 21

Comment: Another question. Do you still have the debug version of the app installed (side loaded) on the devices? If so, you probably won't be able to install the release version from Google Play.